# A question on divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

> For what values of $x,y \in \{1,2,3,...9 \}$, does $$10x+y \space\mid
>  100x + y $$ ?

What approach should I take for solving this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just list them-there are $81$ cases to try if $x$ and $y$ are allowed to be equal, $72$ otherwise.  This is not as silly as it sounds.  Even if there are too many cases to list them all, trying some small ones sometimes is enlightening.  Or you could use the fact that $a|b \leftrightarrow a|(b-a)$

Comment: How do I use $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a, b-a)$ here ?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: It seems there are only 3 solutions (found by doing a bit of calculations). Is there a rigorous way to demonstrate this ?

Comment: Just trying them all is perfectly rigorous.  I agree there are three:  $10x+y=15,18,45$.  They are easy to find if you write it $10x+y|90x$ and think about what divides $90$, but I don't have an easily stated proof that there are no more.  I just made an Excel sheet to check.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dfrac{100x+y}{10x+y}=d\iff \dfrac xy=\dfrac{d-1}{100-10d}$

$\dfrac{100x+y}{10x+y}-10=-\dfrac{9y}{10x+y}<0\implies d<10\implies d\le9$

As $1\le x,y\le9,\dfrac19\le\dfrac xy\le9\implies\dfrac19\le\dfrac{d-1}{100-10d}\le9$

$\dfrac{d-1}{100-10d}\le9\iff d\le\dfrac{901}{91}<10\implies d\le9$

$\dfrac19\le\dfrac{d-1}{100-10d}\iff d\ge\dfrac{101}{19}>5$

$\implies6\le d\le9$

If $d=9,\dfrac xy=\cdots=\dfrac45,\dfrac x4=\dfrac y5=k$(say)$\implies y=5k$ as $1\le y\le9\implies y=5$

Try with $d=6,7,8$

Comment: @Monk, How about this?